# datagrip debug oracle tips please

Tags: oracle, debugging, datagrip

anyone here with ***general tips debugging oracle routines*** and/or packages with **DataGrip** (even getting them to start/work/debug)?

Issues I have are:

**1** Me not understanding the last part of the code dataGrip generates

```
declare
    result NUMBER;
    someVar := 300198032;
begin
    result := FN_GET_CLIENT_ORG_SEQ(V_someVar => someVar );
    open ? for select result as result from dual;
end;
```

at the end has this " **open ?** for select result as result from dual; ", what the heck is the **open ?**

When clicking the button to debug it brings out this dialogue, tried different combinations (numbers, strings, etc.) but oracle complaints and does not run, I end up commenting that line in order to debug.

[image of the dialogue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHVm2.png)

**2** When doing stepping, I noticed that after entering some statements, the debug buttons get disabled (step over, step into, etc). Basically DataGrip just keeps thinking/hangs and I cannot continue to debug.

**Example**, in this case I have to step over in order for debug to keep working, if I do step into, it hangs

```
SELECT something, something
    INTO somethingInto
    FROM some table
```

**Another example,**
any End statmens (that define the ending of the routine) need to be stepped over if not DataGrip hangs or goes into limbo.

**3** Seems to be harder to have DataGrip debug routines contained in packages, either the debug process has issues starting, or step overs are probably the safest way to get it to work.

**Any pro tips would be greatly appreciated**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Datagrip so I can't help.

However, see if this helps with

> what the heck is the **open** ?

Looks like a refcursor *business*. The following code uses the same `open` you saw in your code. It fetches employees that work in department whose `deptno` is equal to the `result` local variable's value.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    result number := 10;
  3    rc     sys_refcursor;               --> this is your "?" - a refcursor
  4    l_name emp.ename%type;
  5  begin
  6    open rc for select ename from emp   --> this is your "open"
  7                where deptno = result;
  8
  9    -- the following code just displays what's being fetched
 10    loop
 11      fetch rc into l_name;
 12      exit when rc%notfound;
 13      dbms_output.put_line(l_name);
 14    end loop;
 15    close rc;
 16  end;
 17  /
CLARK
KING
MILLER

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: thanks mate, did try other type of cursors, but your specific type made it work  !

Answer (score 0):

Aight, seems that things are now smoother thanks to "**stepping over most of the "selects" or "end" lines. (avoids datagrip to hang/enter limbo)**

Also replacing the **?** by declaring a **sys_refcursor**, captures/shows the results, while debugging

```
declare
    result NUMBER;
    someVar := 300198032;

    rc sys_refcursor;  -- < -- HERE

begin
    result := FN_GET_CLIENT_ORG_SEQ(CLIENT_ID => someVar );
        -- HERE (below)
    open rc for select result as result from dual;
end;
```